# How to make my CheckBoxTableCell editable in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

```
isText.setEditable(true);
        isText.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableItem, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<TableItem, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue().getIsText());
            }
        });
        isText.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<TableItem, Boolean>, TableCell<TableItem, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<TableItem, Boolean> call(TableColumn<TableItem, Boolean> p) {
                return new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
            }
        });
```

Here is my code, I really want to check and uncheck that box, and change the original data by the method I defined below,

```
/**
     * Set the boolean value of if this variable is viewed as text
     */
    public void setIsText(boolean newVal) {
        isText.set(newVal);
    }
```

This is my complete implementation of `TableItem`,

```
public class TableItem {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty index;
    private final SimpleStringProperty variable;
    private final SimpleBooleanProperty isText;

    /**
     * Constructor for TableItem
     *
     * @param index
     *      index of the variable
     * @param variable
     *      variable name
     * @param isText
     *      initial boolean value of if it is viewed as a text or not
     */
    public TableItem (int index, String variable, boolean isText) {
        this.index = new SimpleIntegerProperty(index);
        this.variable = new SimpleStringProperty(variable);
        this.isText = new SimpleBooleanProperty(isText);
    }

    /**
     * Get the boolean value of if this variable is viewed as text
     * @return
     *      the boolean value notifies if the variable is text or not
     */
    public boolean getIsText() {
        return isText.get();
    }

    /**
     * Set the boolean value of if this variable is viewed as text
     */
    public void setIsText(boolean newVal) {
        isText.set(newVal);
    }

    /**
     * Get the index of the variable
     *
     * @return
     *      the index
     */
    public int getIndex() {
        return index.get();
    }

    /**
     * Get the string representation of the variable
     *
     * @return
     *      the string of the variable
     */
    public String getVariable() {
        return variable.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens that's different to what you want to happen?

Comment: The checkout box column is not editable by clicking

Comment: Did you make the table editable?

Answer (score 2):

For the `TableCell`s to be editable, you need to set the [`TableView.editable` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#editableProperty) to `true` too.

Furthermore you create a **new property** in your `cellValueFactory`, which means the value edited will not be the property of the `TableView` items, but the new property; the values of your items don't change.

Change the `cellValueFactory` to

```
new Callback<CellDataFeatures<TableItem, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(CellDataFeatures<TableItem, Boolean> p) {
        return p.getValue().isTextProperty();
    }
}
```

and add the following property getter to `TableItem`

```
public BooleanProperty isTextProperty() {
    return this.isText;
}
```